# In SwiftUI with @Charts how to update chart when data changes

Tags: swiftui, charts

I can now receive data from an api as json at regular intervals, and I can update so that it changes an array of data and prints out a new array each time. And I can draw a basic chart. But updating the chart is proving to be an evasive task.

So I’ve searched around and it looks like other people are running into the same issue with charts for SwiftUI. I’m hoping for a pretty direct and simple solution, but that doesn’t mean that I won’t need examples and detail.

Here is where my thinking(and experience) is at right now: as I said the data enters via api and I can print it out to the console as it does. I use a timer var declared in a struct that is like = Timer.publish(30, on: .main, in: .common) etc and then later on in the body use .onReceive(timer, perform: { _ in   etc

So that is how I receive the data regularly , and I assumed that updating the function that contained the chart data would also update the chart, send it does not. It does the first time, meaning that I can make a for loop in a function that  can populate an array of data points within the function, and call it from within chart but only once. So how the bleep can I get it to update the chart as the data updates??? Please.

I’ve read some mention of using @ObservedObject but I’m not exactly sure how to implement.

Can someone help please? This seems to be something that should be simple and ironed out.

I tried looking online for similar issues and looking for answers here on stackexchange, without much success.

………
Update:
Here is some of the basic code from the chart part where the loop and array in the function updates the chart only once.

I guess I’m asking you to assume that there is a couple of data vars(arrays) that are updating within the function regularly to be put into the Data1 and Data2 slots in the function instead of the 1 or 2 being used as sample data . It also probably won’t have a loop in the function but I am using it in the example just to show that the chart does respond to those changes initially.

……while awaiting an answer/help I will also explain that it seems obvious to me now that the entire function will  complete any changes before the chart part executes obviously, even if i put a long pause or delay in the function’s loop cycle. So any update within that function wouldn’t help right? But calling that same function(or a similar one) after the chart is drawn seems to throw errors instead of repopulating the chart.

```
 import SwiftUI
 import Charts

struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Chart{
            var varNameHere = FuncNameHere()
            ForEach(TheDataArray) { item in
                RectangleMark(x: .value("Day", item.day),
                              yStart: .value("Data1", item.Data1),
                              yEnd: .value("Data2", item.Data2),
                              width: 4)
                .opacity(0.4)
            }
        }
        Image(systemName: "globe")
            .imageScale(.large)
           .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
        Text("\(TheDataArray.count)")
    }
  
}
}

 struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
}
}


struct TheData: Identifiable {
var id = UUID().uuidString
var name: String
var day: Int
var Data1: Double
var Data2: Double
}


var cntr: Double = 0

var TheDataArray: [TheData] = []

func FuncNameHere() {
    for x in 0..<5{
        cntr = cntr + 1
        TheDataArray.append(TheData(name: "Datas",day: Int(cntr), Data1: 1, Data2: 2 )
        )
        
    }
 }
```

Comment: Include your code in a [mre]. See [ask]

Comment: In SwiftUI, the `View` won't respond to global variables like you have there. You may want to check out some SwiftUI tutorials and check out the basics of `@State` and potentially `ObservableObject`

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) all of this is pretty basic stuff

Comment: You know how they say a picture is with a thousand words? I think an example is maybe the same way. It would clarify a lot for me, please. Just a simple example of a chart updating its data. I figure that if it’s done with variable changes then it shouldn’t matter if it’s a button  or however else  it  stimulates the change.